# Setting a post's category

Tags: plugin-development, php, theme-development, customization

I'm creating new categories with **galleries** taxonomy :

```
$wpdb->insert("wpem_terms", array(
    'name'=>'Custom Category',
    'slug'=>'customcategory',
    'term_group'=>0,
));

//id of term
$id = $wpdb->insert_id;

$wpdb->insert("wpem_term_taxonomy", array(
    'term_id'=>$id,
    'taxonomy'=>'galleries',
    'description'=>'',
    'parent'=>'',
    'count'=>'',
));
```

It's working. 
And then i'm trying to publish a new post with this newly created category :

```
wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_author'=>1,
    'post_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_date_gmt'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_content'=>'',
    'post_title'=>'',
    'post_excerpt'=>'',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'comment_status'=>'closed',
    'post_name'=>'',
    'post_parent'=>0,
    'post_type'=>'portfolio', // with 'portfolio' custom post type
    'post_category'=>array($id),

));
```

This is publishing post , it's OK but post's category isn't **Custom Category** . I think this line invalid :

```
'post_category'=>array($id),
```

Any ideas? Also i tried this :

```
'post_category'=>array(get_cat_ID("Custom Category")),
```

Comment: Your syntax looks correct. Echo $id just to make sure it is set properly.

Comment: @imHavoc , it's printing right ID . There isn't any problem .

Comment: If you use this: `'post_category'=>array(intval($id)),` do you still get the same problem?

Comment: Yes. I've tried `array(intval($id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
$insert_post = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_author'=>1,
    'post_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_date_gmt'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_content'=>'',
    'post_title'=>'',
    'post_excerpt'=>'',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'comment_status'=>'closed',
    'post_name'=>'',
    'post_parent'=>0,
    'post_type'=>'portfolio', // with 'portfolio' custom post type
    'post_category'=>array($id),
));
if( $insert_post ) {
    wp_set_object_terms( $insert_post, intval( $id ), 'galleries');
}
```

Using [`wp_set_object_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) you can set the terms for the post in any taxonomy. The first argument is the **ID of the post**, the second argument is the **ID or slug of the term**, and the third is the **name of the taxonomy**. If you use an ID for the term, you must use `intval()` otherwise it will create a term that is just a number.

Comment: wp_set_object_terms' first argument is $insert? or $insert_post ?

Comment: Sorry, it would be `$insert_post`, must have missed that.

Comment: not working : `wp_set_object_terms( $insert_post, intval( $id ), 'customcategory');` or `wp_set_object_terms( $insert_post, intval( $id ), 'Custom Category');`

Comment: Leave the word 'category' as-is in the code to set the category, the third argument for `wp_set_object_terms` is the type of taxonomy that is being added to the post.

Comment: i'll add my post to **Custom Category (slug:customcategory)** category. This category in **galleries** taxonomy

Comment: Oh you're right, the third argument can be the name of another type of taxonomy or post_tag. It's very odd that's not working, I resolved the same issue with the code I posted. Read on here if you want: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

Comment: OK i got it , 3th argument is **taxonomy** so it should be **galleries** :) `wp_set_object_terms($postid, $categoryid, $taxonomy)`'s mean is *add this post to this category ($categoryid) which in $taxonomy taxonomy* :) If you update your answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: Updated my answer, glad I could be of assistance. :)